# Emacs SplitScreen and GnuScreen Causing Line Wrap Problems

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, gnu-screen

I have gnuscreen on with multiple "tabs" open. Emacs is on tab 0.

When I tab to a different screen and return to Emacs, the lines do not wrap properly anymore. They blend into each other. If I have a vertical split open in Emacs, the two views blend into each other as if the bar in the middle fails to constrain the line wraps.

How do I prevent this? This is in Terminal.app and the only solution I've found is to force a redraw by dragging the corner slightly. That's not a good long term solution.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but couldn't.  Here are some suggestions: 1) start emacs with emacs -Q to rule out a problem with your configuration, 2) use a different terminal emulator to rule out problems with the one you are using, 3) try tmux to rule out problems with screen.